# Collecting Event Logs using Windows APIs without Admin privileges

Tags: c++, windows, event-log

I'm trying to collect the event logs and I want to to do it without the admin privileges.

This is my code..

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "wevtapi.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winevt.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BOOL flag=EvtExportLog(
                    NULL,
                    L"%SystemRoot%\\System32\\Winevt\\Logs\\System.evtx",
                    L"*",
                    L"D:\\SomePath\\Des.evtx",
                    EvtExportLogFilePath
            );
    int i = GetLastError();
}
```

When I try to do this I get Access Denied error. I'm able to view the event logs using `eventvwr` and i can get the path of the log file which is `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\System.evtx`, but again when i try to view it by putting the path on `run` i get access denied.

I want to copy that `.evtx` log file without any admin privileges, so is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seperate permissions are given to the `EventLog`, so by using the eventlog APIs we can get the eventlogs.So whenever we open the `eventvwr` its get opened through the eventlog permissions.

So if an authenticated user wants to get the eventlogs he has to go thruogh eventlog APIs. The fourth parameter in the `EvtExportLog` is `EVT_EXPORTLOG_FLAGS`
which defines values that indicate whether the events come from a channel or log file.

So in above code a authenticated user cannot access the eventlog file without eventlog APIs that is `eventvwr`, to do that we have to change the flag in the `EvtExportLog` as `EvtExportLogChannelPath`from `EvtExportLogFilePath`.

So above code can be modified as...

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "wevtapi.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winevt.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    BOOL flag=EvtExportLog(
                    NULL,
                    L"System",
                    L"*",
                    L"D:\\SomePath\\Des.evtx",
                    EvtExportLogChannelPath
            );
    int i = GetLastError();
}
```

This code will give the `SYSTEM` logs in the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting event log files may not be possible if you do not have appropriate elevated privileges.

But, you can consume all the events using XPATH queries. 
You an use some XML parser to parse them later.

Here is how to do it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd996910(v=vs.85).aspx